# Upload files to google drive from post form

Tags: python, flask, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-client

Im trying to upload file from user's form, using post method:

```
@main.route('/gupload/', methods=['POST'])
def google_upload():
    Drive.Google.put_file(request.files['file'].filename, request.files['file'].read())
    return redirect(url_for('main.update_page'))

@staticmethod
def put_file(name, file):
    Google.refresh_token()
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=pickle.loads(session['google']['credentials']))
    body = {
        'name': name,
        'parents': [{'id': Google.get_root_dir_id()}]
    }
    file_media = MediaFileUpload(file)
    responce = drive_service.files().create(body=body, media_body=file_media).execute()
    return responce
```

But i get error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: b'{"web":{"client_id":"--secret--","project_id":"intouch-265519","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"--secret--","redirect_uris":["http://127.0.0.1:5000/vk/google_login_response"]}}'
```

I get file by: `request.files['file'].read()` then i call my own method `put_file`, next step is making media_body by `MediaFileUpload` method, example of using:

```
MediaFileUpload('cow.png', mimetype='image/png',chunksize=1024*1024, resumable=True)
```

My issues is that I don't know how transfer file from user's form to google drive api, because `MediaFileUpload` required file in server storage, but i cant save file on my server, because it's too long.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution of your issue, in your script, Drive API v3 is used. So how about modifying from `'parents': [{'id': Google.get_root_dir_id()}]`, which is for Drive API v2, to `'parents': [Google.get_root_dir_id()]` for v3? But I'm not sure about `Google.get_root_dir_id()`. So if this didn't resolve your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks, i didnt notice this! That means a had two problems in my code :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Sorry, but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about your current issue?

Comment: I cant upload file to google drive, from user form on my web page, I using flask, at first send file to server by post method, and then getting t its by request.file method, then I try to use google drive api python sdk to upload him to the server, by use MediaFileUpload, but this method accept only byte instance, I tried convert file to bytes by file.read(), but it also didn't work, i get filenotfound issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I couldn't understand about your situation from your replying. When I could correctly understand about it, I would like to think of the solution.

Comment: My English is poor too, maybe that's reason why you can't understand... Later i edit my topic, and make its more clear.

Comment: I edited my topic, maybe that's help you to understand me.